# Next.js dynamic route shows up in google search

Tags: routes, next.js

I have a weird one. I am using Next.js dynamic routes in my project. It works correctly however I came across a link to my site in Google search and the link was `https://www.coffeeclass.io/tags/[tag]`. Note the `[tag]` in brackets at the end. I am not sure why google thinks this is a page. Is there a way I can tell google that this is not a link? I thought next.js took care of that. The page does redirect to a 404 and it is not listed in my sitemap.

Comment: Do you perhaps link to `https://www.coffeeclass.io/tags/[tag]` incorrectly somewhere in the website? You can setup your website on Google Search Console to better pinpoint where that URL is coming from.

Comment: I am using Next.js Next/Link component which does take in an `as` prop which is `as="/tags/[tag]"` but it also takes a `href`. I don't believe that is the problem because it is in many Next.js examples on their official docs but I will look into it. How can I set up google search console better to pinpoint where this url is coming from? Do you have a link to a helpful site?

Comment: @juliomalves I was able to find it! I had one instance of a `href` pointing to `href="/tags/[tag]"` Thanks for your help!